# Angular Data updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good afternoon I'm developing a project with angular js
and i have a page with a list of items that gets updated depending on the gps coordinates of the smartphone.

When I stay on the same page everything works perfectly and the page gets updated with the correct items

But when I change to a different page and then go back to the page with the list then the data  gets updated in the model (checked with a console.log -> there are items in the array) but then when you look at the web page the list is still empty

snippet from html page (the list)

```
<label class="item item-radio" ng-repeat="project in projectsAtLocation">
            <input type="radio" name="projects" ng-model="info.currentProject" ng-value="project.id">
            <div class="item-content">
                {{project.name}} - {{project.customer}}
            </div>
            <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
        </label>
```

methods in the controller which adjusts the data for the list (these methods are called when the controller gets created and when the gps coordinates change)

```
        $scope.clearCurrentProjectsAtLocations = function () {
        console.log("current projects cleared");
        while ($scope.projectsAtLocation.length > 0) {
            $scope.projectsAtLocation.pop();
        }

        //$scope.projectsAtLocation = null;
    };

    $scope.updateCurrentProjects = function (locationId, callback) {
        //$scope.projectAtLocation = [];

        ProjectLocationDbService.getAllByLocationId(locationId,
            //Success
            function (tx, results) {
                //Success
                if (results.rows.length != 0) {
                    //Track on a project
                    //Update the list of projects at the current location

                    TrackingService.setProjectsAtLocation(results.rows);
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                        $scope.projectsAtLocation.push(results.rows.item(i));
                    }


                    //If we only 1 project at the current location ==> start automatically tracking at it
                    if (results.rows.length == 1) {
                        $scope.info.currentProject = results.rows.item(0).id;
                    }

                    $scope.$apply();
                }

                callback();
            },
            //Error
            function () {
            }
        );
    };
```

I think the code is quite self explanatory but if you got a question about the code ill do my best to answer

And i will greatly appreciate any feedback to help solve this problem

Regards,
Bavo

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? And if not, have you tried wrapping the code that updates scope variables in a function passed to $scope.$apply() instead of updating the variables and then calling $apply() with no parameters?

Comment: I will try this ill keep you posted

Comment: That change probably won't solve your problem but it may help you to see errors as they occur.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion with the $scope.$apply() it helped me to rule out other possibilities and i found the solution, when going to another page and then returning to the page where i had the problems, a new array would be made and the databinding was broken. i now stored the listdata in a service and my controller gets that data